# How to localize percentage values in Dart/Flutter correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I am still looking for a better way to localize a percentage value in Dart/Flutter. So far, I'm just converting a percentage value to a suitable string with the following code: `'${(_percentage * 100).toStringAsFixed(3)}%'`

For a percentage value of e.g. 65.7893 you get the following string: `65.789%`. That's fine for English, but not for other languages.

For example, for German, the string should be as follows: `65,789 %`

### Solution

Thanks to the useful tips, I have now created the following wrapper function.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

 _generatePercentString(percentValue) {
    var systemLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    var numberFormatter = NumberFormat.decimalPercentPattern(
      locale: systemLocale.languageCode,
      decimalDigits: 3,
    );
    var percentString = numberFormatter.format(percentValue);
    return percentString;
  }
```

Comment: Does [`NumberFormat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) (specifically, [`NumberFormat.percentPattern`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.percentPattern.html)) from `package:intl` not do what you want?

Comment: `NumberFormat.percentPattern` requires a `locale` string, although I only want to use the system language.

Comment: The locale argument is optional.  I presume it uses the current locale if not specified.

Comment: In my tests with different locals, the generated strings were always appropriate for English.

Comment: If that's the case, then you could pretty trivially create a wrapper function or extension method that automatically calls it with the current locale.

Comment: That would be an easy solution to implement. I guess there is no simpler solution with even less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add intl package into your pubspec.yaml

Use the Localisation and NumberFormat class.

```dart
Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context); /* gets the locale based on system language*/

String languageCode = myLocale.languageCode;

print(NumberFormat.percentPattern(languageCode).format (60.23));
```

You can refer here for the the supported locales :
https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-formatting-currency-with-numberformat#supported-locales

Comment: I would like to avoid specifying a `locale` string for each percentage value, because the formatting should only match the system language.

Comment: I've updated the answer to solve your query.

Comment: I will create a wrapper function for it.

Comment: `languageCode` is a getter.

Comment: Sorry, It was a mistake, my bad, it's a property